# Using MPFR (mpreal) with Eigen3

Tags: eigen, mpfr

I've seen on the Eigen3 website that there is an "unsupported" module for MPFR multi-precision data type. Does anyone know how reliable this is?

My main goal is not only to use mpreal, but complex < mpreal >.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine so far for me and gives as far as I can tell the correct results.

However you will run into problems when trying to do complex as others have pointed out that complex only works with built in datatypes. Currently I don't know how to produce arbitrary precission complex numbers.